# How to Horizontally align items within a List with React and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to using React and Material UI, and I'm having a little difficulty styling the current page I'm working on. I've created a page that displays football fixtures using the List component from Material UI, and I'm trying to align the items within the list so that the fixture's time would be in the exact same position as you go down the list.

The following website is an example of the styling I'm looking to achieve:
[Premier League Fixtures Website](https://www.premierleague.com/fixtures)

Here is my React code:

```
  const Fixtures = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

  const [fixtures, setFixtures] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "/api/fixtures/"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setFixtures(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Group fixtures by date
  const groupedFixtures = {};

  fixtures.forEach((fixture) => {
    const date = fixture.date
    if (!groupedFixtures[date]) {
      groupedFixtures[date] = [];
    }
    groupedFixtures[date].push(fixture);
  });

  return (
    <Box style={{ margin: "20px 70px", height: "80vh", overflow: "auto" }}>
      {Object.entries(groupedFixtures).map(([date, fixtures]) => (
        <div key={date}>
          <Typography m="20px 0px" variant="h4" component="h4">
            {date}
          </Typography>
          <List
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: "100%",
              bgcolor: colors.primary[400],
            }}
          >
            {fixtures.map((fixture) => (
              <ListItemButton key={fixture.id}>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={
                    <>
                      {fixture.team1}{" "}
                      <span
                        style={{
                          margin: "5px",
                          padding: "5px",
                          borderRadius: "4px",
                          backgroundColor: colors.primary[300],
                        }}
                      >
                        {fixture.time}
                      </span>{" "}
                      {fixture.team2}
                    </>
                  }
                />
              </ListItemButton>
            ))}
          </List>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Fixtures;
```

This is how the page looks:
[image: My Website]

**EDIT**I changed the code to try using a table instead, but I'm having the same problem.

Updated Code:

```
    <Box style={{ margin: "20px 70px", height: "80vh", overflow: "auto" }}>
    {Object.entries(groupedFixtures).map(([date, fixtures]) => (
      <div key={date}>
        <Typography m="20px 0px" variant="h4" component="h4">
          {date}
        </Typography>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table sx={{ maxWidth: 1200, bgcolor: colors.primary[400] }}>
            <TableBody>
              {fixtures.map((fixture) => (
                <TableRow key={fixture.id}>
                  <TableCell align="center">{fixture.team1}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">
                      <span
                        style={{
                          margin: "5px",
                          padding: "5px",
                          borderRadius: "4px",
                          backgroundColor: colors.primary[300],
                        }}
                      >
                        {fixture.time}
                      </span>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">{fixture.team2}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    ))}
  </Box>
```

An updated view of the website:
[image]

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/ use this  to make data align

Comment: So use a table instead of a list?

Comment: yes! it makes data align or looks good

Comment: I tried that solution and I'm having the same issue, the 'time' is never aligned across all rows / tables

Comment: show the results as well as code

Comment: I've updated the post with the new code / results. The time is still aligned differently in each table.

Comment: it looks better. now the next issue to resolve by styling.